# Switching to Nvidia Graphics Card, using prime-select nvidia?

Tags: 22.04

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. I would like to switch to my nvidia gpu, it's currently using the integrated gpu. I've used the command prime-select nvidia but when I go to settings -> about it still says i'm using the Intel gpu?

The current gpu that is being used is NV137 / Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 630 (KBL GT2). I want to switch to my nvidia 1050Ti. I'm not sure if my laptop has hybrid graphics or a desktop with a dedicated GPU. I do not know why my laptop was not already using my nvidia 1050Ti. The card was not recently installed, when I was using windows it was using my 1050Ti fine. The exact command I used was 'sudo prime-select nvidia' (excluding apostrophes). The output of the command was [this](https://paste-bin.xyz/970802#). The reason I know i'm still only using the Intel GPU is it says it in the about section of the settings and when I play games they all use that GPU instead of my 1050Ti. I do not know what Nvidia driver version I have. I haven't manually installed anything regarding to nvidia because I figured it would already have it.

Comment: did you reboot after prime select ?

Comment: I updated my post with the information Nmath asked for

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the MOK process?  The NVIDIA drivers require being registered via MOK.  In the app "Software & Updates", click on the "Additional Drivers" tab.  If the driver selected is not an NVIDIA driver, then you will need to select the proper driver for your card.  After that, I think it will ask you for a MOK password.  This is a password that you will need to utilize on the next system reboot.

The next time you reboot, they system will open some character cell looking screens that you will have to navigate using the TAB key to get to the next prompt area (the mouse does not work).  I no longer have the screens to recreate this, but it was not overly obvious to me when I went through this myself.  Once you have completed that process, it should show the NVIDIA drivers in the About section of settings that you referenced in your initial post.

Good luck, it took me a while to figure out how to get mine NVIDIA working as well.